# 10k Curl post request to splunk

Tags: json, bash, curl, request, splunk

I have a workflow that generates around 10k json files, im using a bash script which uses curl to post these json to Splunk as an event.

Each post request take time, is there an efficient way to post these 10k json to splunk endpoint ?

I had these 10k value in one single json file but due to limitation of Splunk (splunk can only handle a number of characters that json has around 1,2milion character ), so suggested to split it and make each value in that json as a new json so splunk can handle it as separate event, so i end up generating 10k json.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you've answered your own question - namely, the JSO blob you're trying to POST is too big for the [HEC](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/Data/UsetheHTTPEventCollector#Configure_HTTP_Event_Collector_on_Splunk_Enterprise) to handle

Split it into smaller chunks instead of trying to batch it all at once